# DateTime format possible to implement on reader.read?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

I am very new to c# and visual studios 2015 so any opinions are happily accepted(even bad ones).

Is there a way to directly pull out DateTime to a format of "ddd" using reader.read like for example:

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[1].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

I have a very basic grasp of DateTime to string but not sure if the it can be placed in reader.read or not.

My data table contents is this:

[image: Imgur]

And my textBox1 shows this:

[image: Imgur]

Trying to make that text box show "Thu" instead of the date from my code below:

```
if (btnSearch.Text == "Search")
        {                
            string sqlStmt = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_employees WHERE emp_id = @emp_id;";


            using (SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {

                SqlCommand dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, dbCon);
                dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", txtSearchID.Text);

                dbCon.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {                       
                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[1].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
                }

                reader.Close();
                dbCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Sql:

```
[day_received]                       Date   NOT NULL,
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ok I got the wrong title question.... Title should be is DateTime format possible to implement on reader.read..

Comment: So [edit] your question and correct the title. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks ken. Also new to stackoverflow. :)

Comment: What is "reader"? Here's some generic guidance on parsing DateTime data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is the datatype of the field in your sql query? Are you returning a true datetime from mysql, or a varchar representation of a datetime? (Note that the former is pretty much always the better choice).

Comment: @Jacob clarified reader in above code. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn updated my post to clarify. returning true datetime from mysql.

Comment: If you're using `SqlConnection`, you're not using MySql. MySql and Sql Server are two very different database engines. Please get those tags right.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  if(reader.Read())
  {
    /// Considering GetDateTime returns a DateTime object...
    DateTime dtTemp = reader.GetDateTime(fieldIndex);
    textBox1.Text = dtTemp.toString("dddd");
  }
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was thinking of making it outside since i wasn't sure it was possible. 100% working. :)

Comment: This is pretty much a direct copy of an answer posted 40 minutes earlier. The biggest difference is formatting of the code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I don't think so... what he was specifically looking for was conversion to dddd format which was not in earlier posts...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your `reader` object is of type `MySqlDataReader`, a modification of the following should work:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    if(reader.Read())
        textBox1.Text = reader.GetDateTime(fieldIndex)
                              .ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Now to rack my brains up and make it show DateTime format "ddd". Thanks!